# Javascript listener on load - not loading

Tags: javascript, html, dom, addeventlistener

I have a JS listener to check file type on file upload (input type file).

I placed it in the head of the document. It should work on load but it's not working.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById('confirm').addEventListener('change', checkFile, false);
 approveletter.addEventListener('change', checkFile, false);

function checkFile(e) {

var file_list = e.target.files;

for (var i = 0, file; file = file_list[i]; i++) {
    var sFileName = file.name;
    var sFileExtension = sFileName.split('.')[sFileName.split('.').length - 1].toLowerCase();
    var iFileSize = file.size;
    var iConvert = (file.size / 10485760).toFixed(2);

    if (!(sFileExtension === "pdf" || sFileExtension === "doc" || sFileExtension === "docx" || sFileExtension === "png") || iFileSize > 10485760) {
         txt = "File type : " + sFileExtension + "\n\n";
        txt += "Size: " + iConvert + " MB \n\n";
             txt += "Please make sure your file is in pdf or doc format and less than 10 MB.\n\n";
        alert(txt);
     }
 }
}
 </script>
```

My HTML

```
 <input type="file" name="file" id="confirm">
```

I can make this work in the fiddle but not in my document - http://jsfiddle.net/4JHgk/

Comment: Shouldn't `var var iConvert = (file.size / 1000).toFixed(2)`? Also, you should probably do a case insensitive `if(!(sFileExtension.match(/^(pdf|doc(x)?|png)$/i)) || iConvert > 10)`. Different Browsers will have your file extensions capitalized.

Comment: Made the change to the file size. It's now giving the correct file size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your script tag appears after your html declaration of the input and/or wrapt your function, like this:

```
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById('confirm').addEventListener('change', checkFile, false);
approveletter.addEventListener('change', checkFile, false);

function checkFile(e) {

    var file_list = e.target.files;

    for (var i = 0, file; file = file_list[i]; i++) {
        var sFileName = file.name;
        var sFileExtension = sFileName.split('.')[sFileName.split('.').length - 1].toLowerCase();
        var iFileSize = file.size;
        var iConvert = (file.size / 10485760).toFixed(2);

        if (!(sFileExtension === "pdf" || sFileExtension === "doc" || sFileExtension === "docx" || sFileExtension === "png") || iFileSize > 10485760) {
            txt = "File type : " + sFileExtension + "\n\n";
            txt += "Size: " + iConvert + " MB \n\n";
            txt += "Please make sure your file is in pdf or doc format and less than 10 MB.\n\n";
            alert(txt);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This works. Moved the listener to the footer before the closing of the body.